# Fill Missing Values

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

```
data=data.frame("student"=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4),
                "timeHAVE"=c(1,4,7,10,2,5,NA,11,6,NA,NA,NA,3),
                "timeWANT"=c(1,4,7,10,2,5,8,11,6,9,12,15,3))

library(dplyr);library(tidyverse)
data$timeWANTattempt=data$timeHAVE
data <- data %>% 
  group_by(student) %>% 
  fill(timeWANTattempt)+3
```

I have 'timeHAVE' and I want to replace missing times with the previous time +3. I show my dplyr attempt but it does not work. I seek a data.table solution. Thank you.

Comment: @ i apologize by why is this voted negatively?

Answer (score 3):

you can try.

```
data %>% 
  group_by(student) %>%
  mutate(n_na = cumsum(is.na(timeHAVE))) %>% 
  mutate(timeHAVE = ifelse(is.na(timeHAVE), timeHAVE[n_na == 0 & lead(n_na) == 1] + 3*n_na, timeHAVE))
   student timeHAVE timeWANT  n_na
     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <int>
 1       1        1        1     0
 2       1        4        4     0
 3       1        7        7     0
 4       1       10       10     0
 5       2        2        2     0
 6       2        5        5     0
 7       2        8        8     1
 8       2       11       11     1
 9       3        6        6     0
10       3        9        9     1
11       3       12       12     2
12       3       15       15     3
13       4        3        3     0
```

I included the little helper `n_na` which counts `NA`'s in a row. Then the second mutate muliplies the number of NAs with three and adds this to the first non-`NA` element before `NA`'s

Comment: thanks so much it's great do you know of data.table solution? I ask because the data are so large ~1GB

Comment: no as I'm not a `data.table` expert. But the idea behind should be translated 1:1 into a `data.table` solution.

Comment: thanks so much--do you know of dplyr or any solution to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60378425/data-table-solution-to-new-structured-variable

Comment: just under 3million it is historical student data for the hole district

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach using `'locf'` filling

```
setDT(data)
data[ , by = student, timeWANT := {
  # carry previous observations forward whenever missing
  locf_fill = nafill(timeHAVE, 'locf')
  # every next NA, the amount shifted goes up by another 3
  na_shift = cumsum(idx <- is.na(timeHAVE))
  # add the shift, but only where the original data was missing
  locf_fill[idx] = locf_fill[idx] + 3*na_shift[idx]
  # return the full vector
  locf_fill
}]
```

Warning that this won't work if a given `student` can have more than one non-consecutive set of `NA` values in `timeHAVE`

Answer (score 0):

Another `data.table` option without grouping:

```
setDT(data)[, w := fifelse(is.na(timeHAVE) & student==shift(student), 
    nafill(timeHAVE, "locf") + 3L * rowid(rleid(timeHAVE)), 
    timeHAVE)]
```

output:

```
    student timeHAVE timeWANT  w
 1:       1        1        1  1
 2:       1        4        4  4
 3:       1        7        7  7
 4:       1       10       10 10
 5:       2        2        2  2
 6:       2        5        5  5
 7:       2       NA        8  8
 8:       2       11       11 11
 9:       3        6        6  6
10:       3       NA        9  9
11:       3       NA       12 12
12:       3       NA       15 15
13:       4       NA       NA NA
14:       4        3        3  3
```

data with student=4 having NA for the first timeHAVE:

```
data = data.frame("student"=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4),
        "timeHAVE"=c(1,4,7,10,2,5,NA,11,6,NA,NA,NA,NA,3),
        "timeWANT"=c(1,4,7,10,2,5,8,11,6,9,12,15,NA,3))
```